# I'm getting lines in a treeview after a fast scrolling

Tags: treeview, scroll, lines

I using a treeview in C#. everytime i scroll down, im getting lines all over the treeview.

any help?
Thank you in advanced.
Jad

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? If you're not doing any custom drawing you might have an old video card driver.

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/1Fyyy.jpg

this is how it's displaying after scrolling.
My video card is: Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1),
DELL E178FP.
I don't think its that old